# Why might my Postgres table be growing?

Tags: postgresql

I've got a table that grows under Postgres 9.1. It's a high-throughput table with lots of inserts and deletes, but it should generally remain between 1-2k in terms of number or records. Auto-vacuum is enabled, and we've run manual vacuums. We've checked for locks and there don't appear be any. Running "vacuum verbose;" says that while there are millions of dead records, but "found 0 removable".

What might I have not thought about?

Comment: OK. It looks like the cause was a long running function. The function runs inside a select that creates a implicit transaction, which is why the problem occurs.

Answer (score 8):

Run this query:

```
SELECT * FROM pg_stat_activity ORDER BY xact_start NULLS LAST LIMIT 1;
```

If you get a row back where xact_start is not null and it's anything more than a few seconds old, that's your culprit.  VACUUM cannot remove rows that have transaction_ids greater than or equal to the oldest open transaction in the system (even if it's in a completely different database).  If you terminate that transaction and re-run the VACUUM, you should see more than 0 rows removable.

Answer (score 2):

Stale prepared transactions?

```
SELECT * FROM pg_prepared_xacts;
```

Purely for diagnostic purposes and only if you can afford the lock duration, try seeing if `VACUUM FULL` reduces the table size. Does it actually get the lock and run? I would recommend [setting a `FILLFACTOR` of 50 or less](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4160570/changing-fillfactor-of-exisiting-table) before running it, otherwise the table will immediately grow rapidly to return to steady-state size. See [storage parameters](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtable.html#SQL-CREATETABLE-STORAGE-PARAMETERS). Do the same to the indexes, since otherwise they'll have to be grown again too.